# Sorting- Order By Likes and ID from database in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a database of some products and each row has a likes column. I want to fetch the previous 2 entries with query Product.
I have a database like this -

```
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   id   |  image   |   likes   |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   16   |    A     |    80     |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   29   |    B     |    82     |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   12   |    c     |    83     |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   24   |    d     |    83     |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   30   |    f     |    83     |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   14   |    g     |    84     |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   17   |    h     |    84     |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   25   |    i     |    85     |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
```

I am getting data by id like this from the database-

```
public function display(Request $request)
    {
        $image = $request->input('image');

        $product= Products::query()
            ->where('image', $image)
            ->firstOrFail();

        $previous = Products::where('likes', '=', $product->likes)
    ->where('id', '<', $product->id)
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')

    ->union(
        Products::where('likes', '<', $product->likes)
        ->orderBy('likes','desc')
    )->limit(2)->get();

       

        return $previous;
    }
```

Main problem is of LIMIT. if id is 12, it works fine and if id is 24 then I have to set limit in "1" in 1st query and 2nd query.

Comment: Your problem is not clear, and the code you've provided seems to have nothing to do with your question. I see nothing about "Product" or "likes" in this code.

Comment: @miken32 edited the question and code.

Comment: @miken32  updated the question with some solution and clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the concept you're struggling to describe here is that you want to obtain the `row number` not the `record id` when you `order` your `records` by the `likes` field. Unfortunately `MySQL` doesn't have a native `row number` feature so you have to do some additional work to get that.

One such method would be to select the records from the database ordered by the `likes` column and then find the `row number` from there. The caveat to this method is that you're **storing all your records in memory**. If you only have a few records this might not be an issue, however, will be an issue for large data sets.

```php
/**
 * In order to limit memory consumption,
 * get just the `id` field for the records
 * order them by `likes` ascending
 */
$records = Design::orderBy('likes')->select('id')->get();

/**
 * Search the records for record with the desired `$id`
 * then return the `index` of that record in the collection
 * Note that the `index` is zero indexed
 */
$position = $records->search(function ($record) use ($id) {
    return $record->id === $id;
});

/**
 * Use the `$position` as a starting point to skip to in the `$records`,
 * subtract 2 from the `$position` and take 5 results meaning,
 * you get your desired record plus the 2 before and after it
 */
$return = $records->skip($position - 2)->take(5)->pluck('id');
```

**Update**

You say you have a big database (that's what everyone says) so I assume loading `ids` into memory is not an option. Therefore the simplest solution I could come up with was to create a `view` in `MySQL` which has a computed `position` column that can be used as a point of reference.

```
CREATE VIEW `product_rankings` AS
SELECT
  *,
  FIND_IN_SET (
    likes,(
      SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(
          likes
          ORDER BY
            likes ASC
        )
      FROM
        products
    )
  ) AS position
FROM
  products
  ORDER BY position, id
;
```

You can then do something like the following:

```php
$product = DB::table('product_rankings')
    ->where('id', 12)
    ->get();

$result = DB::table('product_rankings')
    ->where('position', '<', $product->position)
    ->orderBy('likes')
    ->get();
```

You can apply limits and offsets as you see fit.

Comment: wait i got some solution and editing the quetion.

Comment: @mukeshsoni You're always going to have issues because you're using the `record` `id` as a method of filtering after you have ordered your results.

Comment: what is best approach ?

Comment: I’ve given you my answer above. Try it.

Comment: i have big database